# Como fazer uma agregação no mongodb através de um repository no javascript/node?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Eu tenho um repositório que faz uma consulta na coleção `logsMonitrip`. O método abaixo é chamado pelo service quando o usuário tenta fazer uma consulta através do cnpj da empresa, depois disso eu recebo o `xId` da coleção e tento fazer uma agregação entre a coleção `erros`e `logsMonitrip`, onde ambos os `Xids` são iguais, para então retornar os dados que eu preciso.

Espero que seja apenas um erro de sintaxe.

```
let criteria = {};

    if(idLog){
        criteria["idLog"] = idLog;
    }

    if(cnpjEmpresaTransporte){
        criteria["cnpjEmpresaTransporte"] = cnpjEmpresaTransporte;
    }

    criteria["idCliente"] = clienteId;        

    criteria["$and"] = [{"dataHoraEvento": {$gte: dataIni}}, {"dataHoraEvento": {$lte: dataFim}}];

    criteria["$lookup"] = [{from: "erros",
    localField: "xId",
    foreignField: "xId",        
    as: "Logs" }]

    console.info(criteria);
    this._logger.info(`LogRepository - obterLogsCnpj - idCliente: ${clienteId} - idLog: ${idLog} - cnpjEmpresaTransporte: ${cnpjEmpresaTransporte} - dataIni: ${dataIni} - dataFim: ${dataFim}`);

        return this._prepareResult(criteria);
}

_prepareResult(criteria) {
    return this._log.aggregate(criteria, {"_class": 0, "_id": 0}).lean().exec();    
}
```